# Is there a way to override $(VCTargetsPath) from the project file?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, msbuild, projects-and-solutions

I needed to build my software for several different platforms using Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 and MSBuild.  I added the platforms to the $(VCTargetsPath) directory and created the .props and .targets files.  I then copied the files to my configuration management repository, defined a path to the parent directory for the copied files: $(CM_REPO_PATH), and wanted to redirect visual studio to use the files in the repository.

I am able to get the project to work when I create an environment variable on my machine called %MSBuildExtensionsPath% and point it to $(CM_REPO_PATH)\MSBuild.  What I want, though, is to set the $(VCTargetsPath) and/or $(MSBuildExtensionsPath) within the visual studio project, not in an environment variable on every developer's machine.

When I add the property group to do this...

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <VCTargetsPath>$(CM_REPO_PATH)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0</VCTargetsPath>
  <MSBuildExtensionsPath>$(CM_REPO_PATH)\MSBuild</MSBuildExtensionsPath>
  <MSBuildExtensionsPath32>$(CM_REPO_PATH)\MSBuild</MSBuildExtensionsPath32>
</PropertyGroup>
```

...the new platforms are not available (as if the project is still using the default $(VCTargetsPath), rather than the one specified).  Is there a way to override the $(VCTargetsPath) from the project file?

Answer (score 0):

Your initial statement is, that you want to build your project for a number of different platforms.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/visual-cpp-project-extensibility?view=vs-2017 describes in very much detail, how to achieve this in Visual Studio 2017. Hopefully the same is true for the version you are using.

The good thing about this is, you don't need to alter $(VCTargetsPath) at all.